# How to increase browser localstorage size

Tags: javascript, angular

while saving data in localstorge, get the below error. help me how to resolve it.

core.js:4002 ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'SPGoldenRecords' exceeded the quota.

Comment: You might want to take a look at IndexedDB instead if you still want to save client sided data without localstorage limitations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values#2989317